# cannot filter data when using `where` query on firebase_admin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want to get data for ages over 30 using code

`db.collection('persons').where(u"age", u">=", 30).get()`

with a data structure like the following
[image]

but the database does not return any data, just an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that your `age` field is of type String (it’s shown between double quotes in the console), while your query is using a Number (the third parameter passed to the `where()` method).

You don’t show how you create the doc but it’s there that you have to take care of writing this field with the desired type, i.e. Number in your case.

PS: there are probably two typos in your code with the `where()` method: there are two extra `u`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that the age data type is a string :), thank you sir

Comment: Since it’s an age you should probably use a Number. Try to compare the two following strings: 11 and 101